# Append java console to file

Tags: java

I use the following lines to redirect my console output to a file :

```
  PrintStream stream = new PrintStream("console.log");
  System.setOut(stream);
```

Now the file is overwritten with every start of the application, thus losing all previous entries, but i´d like it to append every session to a persistent console logfile. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("console.log", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the second argument to `true`.

```
 try {
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true));
  out.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
```